# How to run code inside a string (equivalent to Ruby's #{})

Tags: perl, string-interpolation

I know we can put any code to `#{}` in Ruby, the code in `#{}` will be computed and then inserted into a string.

Is there any equivalent thing in Perl?

Comment: This is called "string interpolation." A google search revealed [this link](https://perlmaven.com/quoted-interpolated-and-escaped-strings-in-perl).

Comment: `print "dereferenced single element array interpolation: @{[ 11+1 ]}"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Using references in perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References)

> Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a simple scalar variable containing a reference of the correct type
>   ...
>   Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a BLOCK returning a reference of the correct type.

So

```
perl -Mstrict -wE'my $x = 2.6; say "Integer part: ${ \( int $x ) }"'
```

where you can run code returning a scalar inside `\(...)` that takes its reference, then `${...}` dereferences it. Similarly you can generate an arrayref and use `@{...}` around it

```
perl -Mstrict -wE'$_ = q(silly,it,is); say "Got: @{ [ /(\w+)/g ] }"'
```

and similary for a hash. But then this goes with an expression returning a scalar as well

```
perl -wE'say "$_ squared: @{[ $_**2 ]}" for 1..10'
```

which is nicer and is more "commonly" used. Thanks to [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) for a comment.

Keep in mind that `[ ]` imposes the list [context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context), where the return often differs from the one in scalar context (and `\(LIST)` is wrong on other accounts<sup>†</sup>).  A good example is [localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html). The scalar return can be enforced by `[scalar localtime]`. Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for a comment.

Watch that you don't get dragged into using [symbolic references](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references) though. Also see [that in perlfaq7](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-use-a-variable-as-a-variable-name%3f).

This assumes that you are thinking of code in `{...}` being a part of a string.  If you want to have a string and execute what it contains as code, that's what [eval EXPR](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) does.
But please note that there are always better ways to do what you need.

A few examples

```
my $str = sprintf "Squared: %6.3f", $x**2;
my $str = "He said: " . join ' ', split /,/, 'yes,it,is';  #/
say "Variable is: ", ( $x // 'undef');
```

or use a `do { ... };` to evaluate any code in a well restricted scope and return the result, which can then be joined or concatenated with other strings.

The topic is discussed [in perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-function-calls-in-a-string?) and at the end of the `perlref` section linked on top of this post.

---

<sup>†</sup> In `\(LIST)` the reference is taken to every element of the list, `perl -wE'say for \(1,2)'`. Then the comma operator in the scalar context does its thing, discarding left-hand-side operands one after another and `${ \(LIST) }` ends up serving the last element of the list.

Comment: (I changed the example, which indeed used `$x+$y` per ysth comment)

Comment: People more commonly use `"Result: @{[ $x + $y ]}"`, which is prettier.  Or even more commonly use a temporary variable.  sprintf also has its advocates and its place.

Comment: The downside of `@{[ ... ]}`: Compare `"${\( localtime )}"` with `"@{[ localtime ]}"`

Comment: @ikegami Ah, thank you!  I need to mention context and this is the right example (it would be wrong!). Added.  Interestingly, I get `1` from `"${\( localtime )}"` (v5.10 and v5.16), while with for example `$_ = q(ah,no,way); say "${\( m/(\w+)/g )}"` I get the last word.  I guess it's just wrong to allow a list in there.

Comment: And this is OK. Say we have `my @tmp = m/(\w+)/g;`, then `${\( m/(\w+)/g )}` is equivalent to `${\$tmp[0], \$tmp[1], \$tmp[2]}` because `\(@tmp)` returns a list of references to the content of `@tmp` not a reference to `@tmp` itself (see the 2nd bullet in `Making References` in [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References)

Comment: @JairLópez  Good point with `\(LIST)`, what I didn't think of here. Thank you for the explanation.  (And the last item in `localtime` list is whether it is DST now, which it is, thus `1`.).  Added.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use CPAN, [Quote::Code](https://metacpan.org/pod/Quote::Code) could work too.

From the synopsis:

```
use Quote::Code;
print qc"2 + 2 = {2 + 2}";  # "2 + 2 is 4"
my $msg = qc{The {$obj->name()} is {$obj->state()}.};
```